# Django query get objects that are not in other object

Tags: python, django

I have two Django models: Match and MatchRegister. I want to get list of all Matches that are not in MatchRegister object but I'm unable to do so. Could you please help me achieve it?

Below my two classes

```
class Match(models.Model):
    """Model representing Match object"""
    match_number = models.CharField(
        max_length=10
    )
    home_team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='home_team'
    )
    away_team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='away_team'
    )
    match_category = models.ForeignKey(
        MatchCategory,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now
    )
    notes = models.TextField(
        max_length=1000,
        blank=True
    )
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=timezone.now
    )





class MatchRegister(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(
        Match,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`__isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) filter with the correct `related_query_name` (which defaults to the lower case model name):

```
Match.objects.filter(matchregister__isnull=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take list of all the matches connected with a match register and then exclude it from the matches altogether, like this:

```
all_match_registers = MatchRegister.objects.all()

ids_to_exclude = []
for match_register in all_match_registers:
    ids_to_exclude.append(match_register.match.id)

Match.objects.exclude(id__in = ids_to_exclude)
```